# Order of standard normal random variables, all independent

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Let $X,Y,Z \sim N(0,1)$ and $X \perp Y, Y\perp Z, X \perp Z$

A combinatorial argument gives that $\displaystyle P(Z > Y >X) = \frac{1}{6}$ since the possible orderings are $3! = 6$ and each is just as likely.

I would like to for learning and understanding sake compute this without the use of a combinatorial argument.

We have:

$P(Z > Y > X) = P(Z-X > Y-X > 0)$ and in the RHS we can see that the independence disappears.

Initially one could think to try:

$P(Z > Y > X) =^{?} P(Z-Y-X>0 \mid Y- X > 0)P(Y-X>0) $ but the RHS seems to be $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}= \frac{1}{4}\neq \frac{1}{6}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do this is

$$
P(Z > Y > X) = \iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} P(Z > Y > X | X = x, Y = y, Z = z) P(X = x, Y = y, Z = z) dV
$$

and so

$$
P(Z > Y > X) = \iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} P(Z > Y > X | X = x, Y = y) f(x,y,z) dV
$$

hence

$$
P(Z > Y > X) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}^3} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{z}\int_{-\infty}^{y} (1) \cdot e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}e^{-\frac{y^{2}}{2}}e^{-\frac{z^{2}}{2}}dxdydz = \frac{1}{6}
$$

Comment: Except the first line isn't exactly correct as $P(X=x,Y=y,Z=z) = 0$ as these are continuous random variables

Comment: You're right. Put it under an intergral. Should be fine now.